# Lindeberg condition's counterexample (central limit theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

My aim is to find an example where the CLT is true but not the following (equivalent to Lindeberg's) condition:

> Find a sequence of independent $(X_k)\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2_k\right)$, so that they respect the central limit theorem but:
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\sigma^2_k}{\sum_1^n\sigma^2_k}\ne0$

My first try is to take $\sigma^2_k=\displaystyle\frac{1}{k^2}$ so that

$\max_k\sigma^2_k=1$  and $\displaystyle s^2_n=\sum_1^n\frac{1}{k^2}\to L<+\infty$.

But what if I had  $s^2_n\to\infty$?

Comment: The sum of independent Gaussians is Gaussian, so it automatically "respects the CLT theorem."  If $\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2\rightarrow\infty$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\max_k \sigma_k^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2}$ is 0  if the numerator is finite, and is infinity if the numerator is infinite. Notice that the numerator does not depend on $n$, did you want it to depend on $n$?

Comment: numerator is $\max_{k\in[1,..,n]\sigma^2_k}$. My question is: is it possible to find some $\sigma^2_k$ so that $s^2_n\to\infty$ but that limit is not 0?

Comment: So you just want a sequence of variances $\sigma_k^2$ with the property that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\max_{k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} \sigma_k^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma_k^2} \neq 0$? What about exponentially increasing variances?

Comment: exponentially increasing have $\sum\sigma^2_k$ stronger than $\max$, don't they?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "stronger than max."  Certainly the sum of positive numbers is always larger than the max of those numbers.  But you can compute an exponential sum exactly and find your answer that way.

Comment: yes I mean "larger than"... uhmm i can't understand your hint

Comment: Well, my "hint" is basically giving you the answer, you just need to compute the sum in the denominator.

Comment: so my $\sigma^2_k=e^k$ and $s^2_n=\sum^n_1e^k=e^1+e^2+e^3+...+e^n$

$\max_k\sigma^2_k=e^n$ ... but is not $s^2_n\sim e^{2n}$?

Comment: mmm ok done... i wrote huge flase sentence. 

$s^2_n=\frac{e(e^n-1)}{e-1}$ so $e^n/s^2_n\to\frac{e-1}{e}$

Comment: $$\sigma_n^2=2^n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Did pointed out, define $\sigma_n^2:=2^n$. Then 
$$\frac{\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\sigma^2_k}{\sum_{k =1} ^n\sigma^2_k}=\frac{2^n}{\sum_{k =1} ^n2^k }=\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}-1  }      $$
which of course does not go to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

But $\sum_{i= 1}^n X_i / \left(\sum_{k =1} ^n\sigma^2_k\right)^{1/2}  $  is standard normal hence we have the central limit theorem.